# How to wrap a database function inside active record class in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Postgres database function with a signature `account_lives('1', '1', '1')`, I want to wrap the DB function under an active record class. any idea how I can do that? just make sure my Database function expects parameter.
I don't want to execute raw SQL from rails.

Comment: yes, and what have you attempted?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to use `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("account_lives('1', '1', '1')")`, correct?

Why not move whatever logic is in the `account_lives` function into your model?

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord` doesn't have a specific interface for working with database functions. `ActiveRecord::Calculations` contains a few (very useful) wrappers  for aggregate functions like `count()`,`max()`/`min()` etc, but beyond that you're on your own. You can drop in your function call wherever AR allows you to substitute in SQL fragments, for example `#select`, `#count`, `#group`, `#having` etc, assuming the database allows the function to be used in that context.

Comment: Thanks, I am planning to write an own wrapper for the same.